# Share SharePoint Online site for anonymous users?

Tags: sharepoint-online, anonymous-authentication, external-sharing

Is there a way to share site with external users? Ideally for anonymous users (like Extended Web Application + Anonymous access in on-premises versions)?

How do You share sites with external users in Online? I understand that there is 'sharing inside domain' and 'external users'. But some of them do not have MS accounts (outlook, xbox, etc.).. Third option, 'External sharing by link' only works for particular files and folders, not page layouts with lists/libs on it..

The only thing I've found is [Office 365 for B2B extranet sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/create-b2b-extranet), but I don't see much difference between this and usual sharing inside Azure AD domain..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short,** No, the **`Anonymous access`** for SharePoint online sites is **no** longer available since May 2017.

Actually, You can just use `external sharing features` to share content with users outside your organization but this is not considered `anonymous access` as we do in SharePoint On-Prem, it just a sharing feature!